# Access to core data database in other class

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchedresultscontroller

i have a core data database that start from the AppDelegate, and there i'll do this:

```
MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

masterViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

so in this way i can access to the database in the master view, then i want access to the core data in other classes, and i do this:

```
id delegateContext = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegateContext managedObjectContext];
```

but when i add, and access the information, i have some bad Exc access and other error in various part of the code when i try to access to the information of the database, so i think that maybe i have used in bad way the core data, to access the information from other classes.

maybe i have to release the delegatecontext?...i haven't release it in any class i have used it, and if i have release it, where i have do it?

anyone can help me?

Comment: updated answer. Please check..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you are taking delegateContext of type `id` instead of `NSManagedObjectContext` and assigning it to `*context`in these two lines.

```
id delegateContext = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegateContext managedObjectContext];
```

How about adding these lines whenever you need to save or access `managedObjectContext`, check it if its `nil` if `YES` copy it from `Appdelegate`.

```
 if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
 { 
    managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@",  managedObjectContext);
 }
```

Just try to remove your these two lines and add the above if condition I am suggesting. Should work.

> **Update 1: As you are asking I am mentioning steps for creating**
>    **Appdelegate's instance to access global properties.**

```
      #import "AppDelegate.h"
```

after `@implementation` create instance of `Appdelegate`

```
      AppDelegate *app;
```

in `viewDidLoad` method...

```
      app=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

Comment: thank for your answer, so i have to declare the managedObjectContext in the .h file and also release it in the dealloc method?

Comment: Yup. In every class wherever you decide to use Core data you gotta declare `managedObjectContext` in .h file, synthesize and dealloc it in .m file..

Comment: ok thank you very much! tonight i try, but for now i accept the answer :)

Comment: AnyTime.. :-)) Will work for sure because my current project on Core data working  prefect this way..

Comment: i have tryed but give me an errore here: (AppDelegate *) and the errore: Use of undelcared identifier 'AppDelegate' i have to import in my .m the AppDelegate.h ?... or i can don't put the (AppDelegate *) ?

Comment: Of course add import appdelegate.h or delete (Appdelegate *)?